# JavaFX callback to Lambda

Tags: java, lambda, javafx-2, java-8

How can I convert this expression in Java 8 with JavaFX2

```
Callback<TableColumn<Factura, BigDecimal>, TableCell<Factura, BigDecimal>> moneyCellFactory =
            new Callback<TableColumn<Factura, BigDecimal>, TableCell<Factura, BigDecimal>>() {
                public TableCell call(TableColumn p) {
                    return new MoneyFormatCell();
                }
            };
```

Into lambda expression.

I try this but is not working with message Incompatible return Type in lambda expression.

```
Callback<TableColumn<Factura, BigDecimal>, TableCell<Factura, BigDecimal>> moneyCellFactory2 =
                      p -> new MoneyFormatCell();
```

The code of moneyFormatCell is this:

```
package com.nettrace.procesarFacturas;
import com.nettrace.common.utils.Formatter;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.text.TextAlignment;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
public class MoneyFormatCell extends TableCell<Object, BigDecimal> {

     public MoneyFormatCell() {

     }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(BigDecimal item, boolean b) {
        super.updateItem(item, b);

        if(item ==null){
            setText("");
        }else{
            setText(Formatter.formatMoney(item));
            setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.RIGHT);
            setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);

            double value = item.doubleValue();
            setTextFill(isSelected() ? Color.WHITE :
                    value == 0 ? Color.BLACK :
                            value < 0 ? Color.RED : Color.GREEN);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That compiles for me. What version of 8 are you using? ea?

Comment: I' using IntellJ IDEA 13 Ultimate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why does your `MoneyFormatCell` `extends TableCell<Object, BigDecimal>` ?
It should be:

```
public class MoneyFormatCell extends TableCell<Factura, BigDecimal> { ... }
```

Your Lambda Expression is correct, the problem resides in the above mentioned snippet.